# Correctly use async/await for REST API

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, promise

I have the following endpoint in the router file.

```
import express from 'express';
import { validatePricing } from "../controllers/BaseController";

const apiRouter = express.Router();

apiRouter.get('/validate-pricing-file', validatePricing)

export default apiRouter;
```

and in the BaseController file, I have the `validatePricing` function:

```
import validatePricingJSON from "../services/ValidationService"

export const validatePricing = async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Validating pricing json file")
     const pricingJSON = fs.readFileSync(sourceDir + '/pricing.json' +, 'utf8')
  const data = JSON.parse(pricingJSON);
   
    await validatePricingJSON(data).catch(error => {
        res.status(error.status).json({
            status: 'Error',
            message: error.message
        })
    })
    res.status(200).json({
        status:'Success',
        message:'JSON validation was completed successfully
    })
}
```

and in the `ValidationService`

```
   export const validatePricingJSON = (filePath) => {
    try {
        if (!obj || !obj[0] || !obj[0].Query) {
            reject('Failed to process JSON: File could have empty content');
  }
     
        resolve('Validation completed successfully)
    } catch (e) {
        reject(e)
    }
};
```

Now when I call the endpoint, the call is not completed and I am not getting any response. I am not sure this is how the `async/await` is used here. Other functions are written like

```
export const validatePricingJSON
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve() / reject()
    }
}
```

but, I am trying to use async/await instead of nested promises. I have more code in the JSON validation for checking missing fields and all and it should return an error or throw an error if the file is not valid and resolve to success if it is valid. I am very new to Node.js and any help here will be appreciated.

Comment: `validatePricingJSON` is not asynchronous. You're explicitly calling `fs.readFileSync` which is the synchronous version. If you want it asynchronous, then *don't* do that and call the async version. Don't just wrap it in a promise for the sake of it. And if you do go for the sync version, then you don't need `async` / `await`.

Comment: I have other validation tests also. Edited the question with one such validation

Comment: Checking a property of an object is still a synchronous operation. Your edit makes no real difference. A synchronous operation does not need `resolve()` or `reject()` or being wrapped in a promise, and as consequence, no need for an `await`.

Comment: so I have removed the async/await and throwing an error like `throw new Error("Validation Failed")`. Then I am getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Validation Failed` and then again the API call is not completed.

Comment: Then 1. You're not using `try / catch` 2. You are still using `async` where you don't need to. All of this code is synchronous.